# Input value isn't being read correctly, comes up as undefined, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a website where the input of a form is being read by JavaScript, but when I execute the alert it says that the value of the input is undefined. Why is that?

Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="reportform">
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="customer"><p>Customers</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="item"><p>Items Sold</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="department"><p>Sales Departments</p>
                <input type="radio" name="report" value="person"><p>Sales People</p>
                <input type="button" name="reportsubmit" value="Submit" onClick="readText(this.form)">
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
            function readText (form) {
            var radio = form.report.value;
            alert("You entered: " + radio);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot get the currently-checked radio button value that way. You have to find the checked one in the list (which is what the value of `form.report.value` will be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the value from the **checked** checkbox like this:

```
function readText(form) {
  var checked = form.querySelector('input:checked');
  var value = checked ? checked.value : null;
  // do something with `value`
}
```

`element.querySelector()` works in IE8+.
`:checked` is a CSS3 thing, I think, so maybe IE9+.

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/mzCV8/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the `checked` property to test which one of your radio button is checked:

```
function readText (form) {
    var radios = form.report;
    for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
        if(radios[i].checked){
            rate_value = radios[i].value;
            alert("You entered: " + rate_value)
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you use jQuery you could simply use:

`$('#reportform input[name="report"]:checked').val();`

Answer (score -1):

your code works fine for me :
http://jsfiddle.net/mzCV8/

ensure that the js code is in front of your form

```
    function readText (form) {
    var radio = form.report.value;
    alert("You entered: " + radio);
}
```

Comment: Chrome adds a non-standard extension to the NodeList interface. I don't know details on how/when the "value" property of a Chrome NodeList is set. Firefox doesn't do that.